# Register receiver objects in Swift wrt message type

Tags: swift, enums, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to implement a kind of publish-subscribe in Swift. In my current case there are messages which are sent only to the receiver and others which additionally require a callback being triggered. For now, I defined an `enum` to hold the different messages, e.g.

```
enum Message
{
    case Foo
    case Bar(() -> Void)
}
```

That is, `Foo` is a message without callback and `Bar` requires the callback. The receiver can apply a switch on the received message and decide. Additionally, a receiver may only subscribe for a subset of message types.

For registration, there is a broker which holds a dictionary of message types and associated receivers. IMO to implement this the ideal solution would be:

```
class Broker
{
    var subscribers = Dictionary<Message, Array<Receiver>>()
}
```

where `Receiver` is a protocol and `Message` is the `enum` defined above. Obviously this won't work, since

1. `Message` is not hashable, and
2. The registration would require a type as argument which is not possible, since this is not a generic.

My current solution is to extend the `enum` with:

```
func hash() -> String
{
    switch (self)
    {
        case Foo : return "Foo"
        case Bar(_) : return "Bar"
    }
}
```

and replacing the dictionary in the broker with:

```
var subscribers = Dictionary<String, Array<Receiver>>()
```

This works, but now the registration requires an instance of the message in order to get the hash, e.g.

```
broker.subscribe(receiver: self, message: Message.Bar({}).hash())
```

This feels awkward - at least to me. I think while this isn't wrong it seems not being the best solution.

So, the question is: what is the best way to subscribe several receivers with different receivable message types, possibly without loosing the `enum`?

Comment: FWIW: I made a blog post about this: [Publish-Subscribe in Swift](http://everythingel.se/blog/publish-subscribe-in-swift/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
enum Message
{
    case Foo
    case Bar(() -> Void)

    static let FooType = "Foo"
    static let BarType = "Bar"

    func hash() -> String {
        switch self {
        case Foo:       return Message.FooType
        case Bar(_):    return Message.BarType
        }
    }
}

broker.subscribe(receiver: self, message: Message.BarType)
```

Comment: Hm, just did not thought about storing a static variable. Now I feel stupid for asking such a silly question...

Comment: Not totally silly, it would be nice if there was a cleaner way to do it.  Ideally something like an enum with a raw type of String, unfortunately you can't use a raw type and enum arguments, so...

Comment: Yeah, plus all other variants I can think of introduce some decoupling between the message type and the registration which is not much nicer.

Comment: Violating SO rules, but I have to say: that works so awesome. I just replaced a bunch of `NSNotifications` with this publish-subscribe and it is so easy and clear now.

Comment: Getting into meta-discussions here, but how is what violating SO rules?

Comment: "Avoid comments like +1 or thanks", it's not really a violation though ;)